# How to change style of Clicked particuler button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have two files
in xml.php i am displaying data from a xml file
also displaying button with xml data by this code

```
<input type="button" id="class" value="Select this Agent" onClick="Selected(this.id);">
```

so buttons displayed on page is equal to elements in xml. and i want to change background color of clicked button.
here is my javascript code for changing style of button

```
function Selected(ClickedId){
        alert(ClickedId);
        ClickedId.css('background-color', 'Green');
    }
```

and whole code is

```
<?php
                $xml = simplexml_load_file("agent.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
                function processXML($node){
                    foreach($node->children() as $agent => $data){      
                        $agent= trim($agent);   
                            if($agent!="" && $agent=='image'){
                                ?><div class="inline"><?php 
                                echo "<br>";
                                echo "</br>";
                                echo "</br>";
                                echo '<img src='.$data.' >';?></div>
                                <!--<input type="button" value="Select this Agent">--><?php
                            }
                            elseif($agent == 'phone'){
                            ?><div class="btqn"><input type="button" id="class" value="Select this Agent" onClick="Selected(this.id);"></div> <?php

                            }
                            elseif($agent!=""){
                                ?> <div class="Table"><?php echo $data;?></div>
                                <?php
                                //echo "</br>";
                            }
                            else{
                                echo "<hr>";
                            } 
                            processXML($data);
                        }
                }  
                processXML($xml);
            ?>
```

So please anyone can tell me where i am wrong.
any suggestion should be appreciable
Please Help

Comment: Is this Vanilla Javascript or jQuery? I can see both, and wrongly done.

Answer (score 3):

Try out

change this line

```
<input type="button" id="class" value="Select this Agent" onClick="Selected(this.id);">
```

to

```
<input type="button" id="class" value="Select this Agent" onclick="Selected(this);">
```

Note here instead of passing id pass `this` reference.

So you can use

```
function Selected(ClickedId){
    alert(ClickedId);
    ClickedId.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
}
```

JQuery

```
$("#class").click(function(){

$(this).css("background-color","green");

})
```

[See Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SK3BW/)

Comment: onclick="Selected(this);" - is obsolete, just remove it from input element as well as Selected() function

Comment: if i had two button with same id then?

Comment: ID should be unique even though it works based on which button you clicked. if it is fine please accept as answer.

Comment: i am genrating more than button with same id at displaying elements from xml

Comment: and if i am select fires button after that i am select another button then first selected button should be unselect. what should i do for that

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
document.getElementById(ClickedId).style.backgroundColor = "green";
```

[Updated part as user requested]

First change from id to class selector as ids are not supposed to be duplicated and pass `this` instead of `this.id`. Also if you want to clear all the other buttons backgrounds you can make use of `getElementsByClassName()` function.
HTML

```
<input type="button" class="class" value="Select this Agent" onClick="Selected(this);">
<input type="button" class="class" value="Select this Agent" onClick="Selected(this);">
<input type="button" class="class" value="Select this Agent" onClick="Selected(this);">
```

Javascript code

```
 function Selected(elem) {
        var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('class');
        for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
            buttons[i].style.backgroundColor = '';
        }
        elem.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }
```

Jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HWKKM/1/)

Comment: If i had two buttons with same id then?

Comment: ids are not supposed to be duplicated. You can use class selector instead.

Comment: i am genrating more than button with same id at displaying elements from xml –

Comment: you could simple pass `Selected(this)` and `function Selected(elem){
    elem.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
}`

Comment: and if i am select fires button after that i am select another button then first selected button should be unselect.
what should i do for that

Comment: I have updated the fiddle. Please check. you can make use of `getElementsByClassName()` function and iterate through it and reset the background color. Check fiddle

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44969/discussion-between-nouphal-m-and-sanjay-rathod)